# React Native : Access to component ref child in FlatList

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm not able to access to component ref child in FlatList. On componentDidMount method, I've only one ref for the FlatList.

Here is my code in case you want to reproduce it:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  AppRegistry,
  FlatList,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from "react-native";

export default class touchable extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          ref="REF-FLATLIST"
          data={[{ key: "a" }, { key: "b" }]}
          renderItem={({ item }) =>
            <Text ref={`REF-FLATLIST${item.key}`}>
              {item.key}
            </Text>}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.refs);
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#F5FCFF"
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent("touchable", () => touchable);
```

I'm using React Native v0.45.1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can set it the ref using the ref callback this way:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  AppRegistry,
  FlatList,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from "react-native";

export default class touchable extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          ref="REF-FLATLIST"
          data={[{ key: "a" }, { key: "b" }]}
          renderItem={({ item }) =>
              <Text ref={(ref) => this.textRef = {...this.textRef, [`REF-FLATLIST${item.key}`]: ref}}>
                {item.key}
              </Text>}
            />
          </View>
    );
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.refs, this.textRef);
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#F5FCFF"
  }
});
```